# Convert .htaccess rule to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to move a site that was born on apache server to a nginx server.
I've the current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(Personal)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^mng/([-0-9a-zA-Z/%&]+)$ /index.php?aurl=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z/%&]+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

An online converter has converted these rules into:

```
location /mng {
   rewrite ^/mng/([-0-9a-zA-Z/%&]+)$ /index.php?aurl=$1 break;
}
location / {
   rewrite ^/([-0-9a-zA-Z/%&]+)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;
}
```

I added them to my nginx configuration but does not work, where am I wrong?
When I visit a page domain.ex/mng/index I can download the page..
This is my complete nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name domain.ex;
    location / {
       rewrite ^/([-0-9a-zA-Z/%&]+)$ /index.php?url=$1 break;
    }
    location /mng {
       rewrite ^/mng/([-0-9a-zA-Z/%&]+)$ /index.php?aurl=$1 break;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me your server configuration?

Comment: I suggest you check this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them

Comment: php7-fpm, nginx but all works great I know this, I can access my resources like index.php?url=1 and works great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts, I solved the problem with the following rules:

```
location /mng/ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /?aurl=$1;
}
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /?url=$1;
}
```