# Definitive LEMP stack official - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx

I've followed the exact process indicated here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

I've been having so many problems getting a localhost nginx stack started. I've searched many and many stacks but none the less I can't figure it out. Although I'm so close, **currently my website is just downloading php files instead of running them.** I'm using vagrant with a virtual box that i've built myself. I kept thinking it's a php5-fpm problem but i do not know anymore.

I need help.

```
  # You may add here your
# server {
#       ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
        #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
        listen 80 default_server;
        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name sandbox.dev.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to index.html
                #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
        }
```

---

nginx.conf

```
vagrant@precise64:/etc/nginx$ cat nginx.conf 
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following location to your server block in your default/ conf file. After that restart nginx:

```
server {

         location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
         }
}
```

For more information refer to: [Nginx serves .php files as downloads, instead of executing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them)

Comment: Now i'm throwing this error: This page isn’t working

192.168.33.14 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 503

Comment: access.log 192.168.33.1 - - [15/Jun/2017:19:22:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"

Comment: hmm, can you curl the php page? say `curl localhost/index.php -v` with the -v switch to debug so you can follow it's path

Comment: I just realized my php-fpm is dead in the water constantly. vagrant@precise64:/etc$ sudo service php5-fpm status
 * php5-fpm is not running
vagrant@precise64:/etc$ sudo service php5-fpm start
vagrant@precise64:/etc$ sudo service php5-fpm status
 * php5-fpm is not running

Comment: I had to uninstall and reinstall it but it's running now.

Comment: awesome feel free to select my answer if it helped you at all.