# 405 error with Ajax POST / Nginx configuration

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send email with an Ajax form and swiftmailer. It works in local but not in production.

When contact_me.php takes parameters not from form but written explicitly the email is sent even from the server so I think Swiftmailer is working.

**contact_me.js**

```
// Contact Form Scripts

$(function() {

    $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                dataType: "text",
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message       
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message                    
                },
            });
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

**contact_me.php**

```
<?php
// Autoload for swiftmailer
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }


$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$email_subject = "TrustPair nouveau contact :  $name";
$email_body = "New form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";

// Add here swiftmailer code, need to return true
// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('mail.gandi.net', 465, "ssl"))
  ->setUsername('name@domain.com')
  ->setPassword('password')
;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Create the message
$message = (new Swift_Message())
    // Give the message a subject
    ->setSubject($email_subject)
    // Set the From address with an associative array
    ->setFrom(['noreply@domain.com' => 'Domain no reply'])
    // Set the To addresses
    ->setTo(['firstmailto@gmail.com', 'secondmailto@gmail.com'])
    // Give it a body
    ->setBody($email_body)
    ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
echo $result;
// result is equal to the nbr of message recipients

if ($result == 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}


?>
```

Comment: does there any errors ?

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 POST http://example.com/mail/contact_me_test.php 405 (Not Allowed)
 send @ jquery.min.js:4
 ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
 submitSuccess @ contact_me.js:22
 (anonymous) @ jqBootstrapValidation.js:76
 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
 r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: Your code is `url: "././mail/contact_me.php"` and the error says: `/mail/contact_me_test.php`. It's not even trying to post to the same file? (and you should also remove the `././mail/...` in front of the URL, and use relative from the root: `/mail/...`)

Comment: I replaced contact_me.php to a new file contact_me_test.php where I don't use input from the form but values that are in the code. When I run "php contact_me_test.php" the email are sent. I changed the path to relative, I always have the same 405 error.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but the code works when I use wamp Virtual Host in local. However if I use browserSync (localhost), I have a 404 error POST http://localhost:3000/mail/contact_me.php 404 (Not Found), I don't run browserSync in prod so I'm not sure of how it can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx server doesn't allow POST request with static page (ie. *.html).

There are [hacks](https://distinctplace.com/2017/04/17/405-not-allowed-nginx-fix-post-requests/) to handle the problem. In my case, it fix the 405 error but the emails weren't send.

The solution was to **change the index.html to index.php**, be sure to [adapt your Nginx configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them) to reflect this changes.