# PHP files not getting executed nginx

Tags: php, nginx

When I was using apache2 it was working fine. `/var/www/html/info.php` which prints `phpinfo();` is not getting executed and simply gets downloaded at `http://localhost/info.php`. My nginx default config(`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`):

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    listen 443 ssl

# SSL configuration
#
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/app.snuba.com/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    error_page 405 = $uri;
}


# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#   deny all;
#}

}
```

Comment: 1. have You installed php-fpm?  2. have You restarted/reloaded nginx after changing config files?

Comment: yes I installed php-fpm just now by installing lamp server but still doesn't work after restarting nginx.

Comment: oh. so... try to stop apache server: `service apache2 stop` and restart nginx `service nginx restart`

Comment: Still its not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx serves .php files as downloads, instead of executing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them)

Comment: @VivekSadh see: `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/app.snuba.com/public_html` but You put Your php files to `/var/www/html`. Is that correct? (:

Comment: No. I already changed it to /var/www/html.

Comment: Thanks. I found it was due to port conflict. I fixed it by changing port number.