# Wordpress site downloading index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress site has no problem till now but suddenly it starts downloading index file while visiting site. Other links of pages on same site and `wp-admin/` are working fine but while visiting home page it downloads `index.php` as download name.

Comment: something is wrong with webserver, which webserver are you using

Comment: You find the following helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them

Comment: scalahosting.its apache not nginx.

Comment: you mind sharing your config file, the relevant parts.

Comment: something not ok with your config file have you updated recently to php 7 or something?

Comment: I will talk to server team. i was just wondering if it wasn't server. Thanks