# Browser downloading PHP files instead of executing them. Webmin + NGinx

Tags: php, nginx, php-7.2, webmin, virtualmin

**The Problem**

I attempted to upgrade from PHP 7.0 to 7.2 today and it resulted in websites on the server downloading through the browser instead of executing like normal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge php7.0 php7.0-common
sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl php7.2-xml php7.2-zip php7.2-gd php7.2-mysql php7.2-mbstring
```

**My Question**

Can anyone provide me some examples of how to debug this? And any additional insight as to what may be going on?

**My Theory**

Technically I don't know what caused this, but my experience tells me it's one line, in one file, coming from NGinx that needs edited.

**What I've Tried**

I found this issue to be commonly reported here on SO. But the solutions have lacked critical information such as the file path, or the file paths they reference don't exist on my system, or the proposed solution doesn't resolve the issue.

Many articles mentioned configurations for  PHP FPM and / or FastCGI. But I'm unable to identify how to confirm whether or not these are installed / running and what a proper configuration looks like for a standard web server.

**What Helped**

I did update my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file from `default_type  application/octet-stream;` to `default_type text/html;` and this has stopped the downloading of files but results in a blank page. Including my phpinfo.php

**My Environment**

- AWS EC2 Small
- Ubuntu 18.04
- NGinx 1.10.3
- Webmin
- Virtualmin

Comment: I got the same problem a few times in an apache envirement. I don't know alot about nginx thought but check the vhost file and also your htaccess. Most of the time thats where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks but only Apache uses .htaccess and I'm running NGinx which uses a global and site specific nginx.conf file.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by checking my vhosts file?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them

Comment: It probably has to do with how you reference the PHP compiler in your config files but like I said I am no nginx expert. Seems like your PHP files are executed instead of being send to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, my settings already matched the ones advised in the post so unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Sorry bro. Try posting your question at https://serverfault.com instead. stackoverflow is more suited for programing questions then server problems.

Comment: Np bro good luck ;-) I actualy have an active post there my self hehe

Answer (score 0):

Your domain configuration NGINX ... It's wrong ...

Missed FastCGI Params ...

Example:

```
location ~ [^ /] \. php (/ | $) {
fastcgi_split_path_info ^ (. + \. php) (/.+) $;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_pass unix: /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $ fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $ document_root $ fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Good luck! Send news about your progress ...