# My site is not opening when I entered my site url, instead its downloading

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, url, error-handling

When I enter my site URL on a browser my site is not opening, instead it's downloading my page. What is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is lacking a lot of details. It appears that your webserver is serving your php files as downloadable files instead of executing them. Depending on the webserver you are using, I suggest you take a look at these previously asked questions:

- **Apache:** [What causes PHP pages to consistently download instead of running normally](https://serverfault.com/questions/215455/what-causes-php-pages-to-consistently-download-instead-of-running-normally)
- **NGINX:** [Nginx serves .php files as downloads, instead of executing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them)