# PHP doesn't work with https, instead it download file

Tags: php, nginx, https, centos

I have nginx as a webserver with PHP-fpm. I can successfully see my website using http but if I use https I will download the index page and the page will not be shown.

My nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server_tokens off;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    client_max_body_size 2M;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name  www.domain.net;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;


        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.net/fullchain.pem; 
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.net/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
            index index.php;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

And conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name  www.domain.net;

root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them  This might be helpfull

Comment: @pr1nc3 hmm it didn't resolve my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your php location tag only exists in the `listen 80` server block.
So if the request is sent to the `443` server block, it doesn't handle any php files. You should add the same php block to the `443 server block`;

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server_tokens off;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    client_max_body_size 2M;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name  www.domain.net;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;


        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.net/fullchain.pem; 
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.net/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
            index index.php;
        }

        # NEW
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
          }
        ## NEW

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the nginx log files? If so; please add them to your original post

Comment: I made it working, I needed to add `index index.php index.html index.htm;
       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
`