# How to execute a PHP script with sensitive data from a plain website that runs on Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

I have a very minimal HTML + JavaScript website, running on an Nginx web server.
I'm using Ubuntu and also have PHP7.2 installed.

I would like to **trigger a PHP script execution** when a button is clicked on the website.
The PHP script contains sensitive data so it **shouldn't be accessible** by the end user.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

---

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="user_input">
        <input type="submit" value="user_submit">       
    </body>
</html>
```

**Nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/wwww/html;
    root index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP code can't be accessed or seen by the user - only those with access to the actual server can see its content.

Comment: Thanks @Qirel so how can I execute the PHP script with the settings I've described above?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to do is submit a form:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="yourfile.php" method="post">
            <!-- Your form fields -->
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then on the php file you will find your inputs in the `$_POST` variable.

Be careful tho: if the webserver is not configured to block a request to that file someone will still be able to access it at http://example.com/yourfile.php and see it plain text. You either need to:

1. configure the webserver to block this request OR
2. (better) put your php script in a folder which is not reachable, and use a php file which would look somehing like this:

```
<?php
// Assuming your script is 1 level below:
require __DIR__ . '/../yourfile.php';
// Launch a function or whatever is needed here.
```

If when submitting the form you download the file instead of executing it, configure nginx along the lines of [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28644277/6797006) (of course, full credit to the OP)