# laravel All routes are downloading index file

Tags: php, laravel

My question is about i finshed creating my api with laravel/lumen but when i finshed uploading the project to server and try to access the routes, it is downloading the index file. What is the problem

Comment: You download the plain source code if the public/index.php file? Looks like php is not installed/configured.

Comment: nginx or apche??

Comment: Your web server is not correctly configured to execute PHP files.

Comment: Are you using [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them) or [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them)?