# Problem when i try to convert the htaccess to nginx file, triggers a download

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

How can i convert this .htaccess to NGINX?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|map)(\?|$) /404error.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried this:

```
  location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

but always when i click to another link to other address it trigger to download a file called `download`

This is an example to normal url
`http://forum.example.net/index.php?/discover/`

how should it be:
`http://forum.example.net/discover/`

I'm using ipboard v4.4.10

Answer (score 0):

try adding a php location block

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php;
}
```

Reference: [Nginx serves .php files as downloads, instead of executing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them)