# Problem in nginx server not running php files suddenly

Tags: php, security, nginx, server

I have a dynamic website developed by native PHP on a server using NGINX which was functioning normally, but suddenly it broke down such that the PHP files no longer run and just download automatically to the client with the code whole source when he tries to excute that files. I don't know why it happened, and is it because of a hacking or an internal server problem. When I contact the web host, he says that a php file that is causing this problem, knowing that I haven't changed anything at last time.
Please clarify the cause of this problem if you have an idea !! Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should check the Nginx Access setting - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them

Comment: Thank you @zimorok. But why did this problem occurred ???

Comment: maybe the server got updated and the Access setting is overwritten with an old backup

Comment: I don't think so, because when the web host makes the restoration, the server works correctly but almost in the same hour of the day before (when the problem occurred), it returns the problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no idea yet ? I add that the last time, the host re-initialized the configuration of the VPS, and the website is now running well. It is clear that the problem was in the configuration! But I ask the same question, why did this failure happen? I want to know the reason: if the problem comes from PHP files or from the server itself !!