# Confused about rewrite rules in NGINX

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm moving a project to use Docker with Nginx, which previously used Apache. It's a simple PHP project, but I can't get the rewriting to work like it did on Apache. The old `.htaccess` is simple;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It redirects all page requests to the `index.php` file with a `page` parameter, which is then parsed in `index.php` with a custom `PageController`. I can't however get this to work with Nginx rewrites and it's confusing me a lot.

The goal is to rewrite URLs like `index.php?page=forgot_password` to `forgot_password`.

My current nginx.conf is

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /app/app;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

which obviously doesn't work since there's no rewrite rules.

I've tried a few other configurations, for example the Nginx configuration in the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx), which redirects all pages to `index.php` but doesn't provide the `page` query parameter.

I've tried other configurations like

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location / {
   if (!-e $request_filename){
     rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 break;
   }
}
```

which causes Firefox to prompt me to download the forgot_password file.

I've had other attempts (which I can't remember sadly) that did seem to work the way I wanted, but caused JS, CSS and other resources to no longer work.

How can I get this working? I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Nginx uses the `try` directive instead of "file exists". So using a [standard WordPress setup](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/), Nginx would try the URL literally (static content), then try the URL with a slash on it (checking for a folder) and then fall back to the index.php with [`$args`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args) passed. This effectively maps one-to-one with the default htaccess version

Comment: The Wordpress example (with some modifications) work in the way the URL is rewritten, but the `$args` are still not passed through so the wrong page is shown, and I don't understand why. Set `cgi.fix_pathinfo` to 0 in my `php.ini` as well, still nothing.

Comment: What I linked to is pretty much the official config, even WP's main documentation recommends it, so I'd start there. I'd grab [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) if you don't have it already and run `wp rewrite flush` just to make sure that nothing is getting cached. (_That is the same as clicking Save Permalinks, just easier sometimes._) Make sure you have the `fastcgi` stuff, too

Answer (score 0):

For the nginx configuration , EITHER rewrite the index as follows:

```
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 break;
  }
}
```

or Alternatively:

```
server {
    server_name yourdomain.com;
    location ~ "^/(.+)$" {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still severely confused, neither of these options individually work, both of them  result into Firefox prompting me to download the file.

Comment: what about other browsers - say chrome ?  (I ask this because I suspect that your firefox may have problems ? please try clearing the cache or re-install it)

Comment: Chrome does the same, I'm genuinely confused. This is my current nginx.conf file; https://pastebin.com/kcUE2wRn

Comment: Just wonder -did u restart ngnix after changing the config file?

Comment: I've been stopping and starting the docker container after every change, and changes to take effect between different attempts.

Comment: Thanks. Do u have another ngnix server ? It is strange that the server is forcing diwnload

Comment: I have some Laravel projects running on Sail which all work fine, but even copying those `nginx.conf` files doesn't fix it. They work to the point the URLs get rewritten, but no query params are being passed through.

Comment: Does this solve your problem ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591040/nginx-serves-php-files-as-downloads-instead-of-executing-them)